# I cannot access Excel file in SharePoint site, unauthorized exception, error code 401

Tags: c#, sharepoint, httpclient, ntlm, csom

I am trying to access an excel file located in a site on sharepoint. I don't have an option of making modification from the server side. I can access the file from chrome,when I enter the link, file automatically downloads. But when I tried to download using C# code (.Net framework 4.6.1), I got Unauthorized exception, 401 error code.
I have tried couple of things.
Firstly I tried CSOM (Client Side Sharepoint Object Model). Code is as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var link2 = @"File link";
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(link2);

            Web web = context.Web;
            context.ExecutingWebRequest += clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;
            context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            context.Load(web);

            ExceptionHandlingScope scope = new ExceptionHandlingScope(context);

            using (scope.StartScope())
            {
                using (scope.StartTry())
                {
                    context.ExecuteQuery();// <- Unautherized exception
                    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
                }
                using (scope.StartCatch())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(scope.ServerStackTrace);
                }

            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        }
```

After that I went back to traditional method and used HttpClient. Code follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var link = @"sitelink";
            var link2 = @"filelink";

            var credential = new CredentialCache
            {
                { new Uri(link2),"NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials}
            };

            var options = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Credentials = credential
            };

            //var client = new HttpClient(options);

            using (var client = new HttpClient(options))
            {
                var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                requestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
                requestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(link2);
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("Use-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36");
                var response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response,Formatting.Indented));
                if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)// <- Status false, Unautherized is in the response header
                {
                    using (var reader = new io.StreamReader(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
                    {
                        io.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Name\source\repos\TestExcel.xlsx", reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result );
                    }
                        
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("DOne");
        }
```

I am new with sharepoint and i appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
One more trial

```
var link2 = @"file link";

            var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            });

            io.Stream resultStream = null;
            try
            {
                resultStream = client.GetStreamAsync(link2).Result;
                var reader = new io.StreamReader(resultStream);
                io.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Name\source\repos\TestExcel.xlsx", reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result);
                reader.Close();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e,Formatting.Indented));
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Complete serialized exception object

```
{
  "ClassName": "System.AggregateException",
  "Message": "One or more errors occurred.",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "ClassName": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
    "Message": "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).",
    "Data": null,
    "InnerException": null,
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": null,
    "HResult": -2146233088,
    "Source": null,
    "WatsonBuckets": null,
    "SafeSerializationManager": {
      "m_serializedStates": [
        {}
      ]
    },
    "CLR_SafeSerializationManager_RealType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException, System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="
  },
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n   at SharePointTrail.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\Users\\name\\source\\repos\\SharePointTrail\\SharePointTrail\\Program.cs:line 27",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": "8\nThrowIfExceptional\nmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=\nSystem.Threading.Tasks.Task\nVoid ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)",
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": "mscorlib",
  "WatsonBuckets": null,
  "InnerExceptions": [
    {
      "ClassName": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
      "Message": "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).",
      "Data": null,
      "InnerException": null,
      "HelpURL": null,
      "StackTraceString": null,
      "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
      "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
      "ExceptionMethod": null,
      "HResult": -2146233088,
      "Source": null,
      "WatsonBuckets": null,
      "SafeSerializationManager": {
        "m_serializedStates": [
          {}
        ]
      },
      "CLR_SafeSerializationManager_RealType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException, System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Update**
Sharepoint is hosted in office 365.
It seems office 365 is taking care of authorization. When i inspect in chrome dev tool, in source file i find couple of js files (names which i cannot mention here).

Comment: This could be because on Chrome you are already logged in. That's why you don't get a 401 on Chrome, but while using C# you are not yet authorized. For that you need to have an access token to your Sharepoint and attach it as a header to your request.

Comment: Thanks @robalem. But i am entirely new to sharepoint. So please help me understand, how will i get the access token? shoud i make Oauth2 exchange ? How to persist that token throughout the lifetime of the application?

Comment: @AdityaNadig the code snippets you posted show a lot of lines that look like random attempts to make something work. Documents in SharePoint are accessible by their URL. You don't need more than 3-4 lines to create an HttpClient with Windows auth, execute a `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync` and write the file to the disk. All the code and headers you added can only *cause* problems

Comment: Without having to explain this all by myself, take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.anexinet.com/blog/getting-an-access-token-for-sharepoint-online/) which describes how to retrieve an access token from Sharepoint Online. After retrieving the token, you can append it to your request.

Comment: As for the CSOM code, it doesn't make much sense and again looks like random code. The ClientContext is used to connect to the site, not download a document. Headers, scopes etc serve no purpose and again, the extra headers will only cause problems. Have you checked the CSOM documentation and examples?

Comment: @robalem we don't even know if the OP is using SharePoint on-prem or onine. The fact Windows authentication is used suggests this is about an on-prem server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried simple versions with both CSOM and httpClient. Same error in both attempts. And yes i went through CSOM documentation and code examples. They are pretty basic and same error persisted in those examples.

Comment: @AdityaNadig first, you need to understand what SharePoint is and how it works. It's not just a site. If you don't know the difference between site collections, sites, lists, documents, you won't be able to use any libraries or even understand what the HTTP calls do. After that, start by reading the docs, eg [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

Comment: @robalem the sarepoint is inside a corp network. I dont know whether it is On-prem or online.

Comment: @AdityaNadig the code you posted has nothing to do with the documentation. The very fact you tried to pass a document URL to the ClientContext suggests you didn't actually read the docs, just copied code. You can't do that with SharePoint. Same with HttpClient - where did all this code come from?

Comment: @AdityaNadig inside a corp network is what on-premise mean. And retrieving a file with HttpClient is a simple `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync` with the full URL as argument. To use Windows Authentication all you need is just `var myClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true });`. If you get a 401 it probably means the account you use to execute your application has no permission to connect to SharePoint or at least, retrieve that specific file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for many suggestions. I tried many variations of  the code snippet that i posted. In all my trails i encountered same Error. For example,before using a file link, i tried to grab the title of the site using CSOM as suggested in the docs. Even that returned with same error. I am in the process of understanding sharepoint. I have downloaded files through HttpClient before using the method you suggested. None of it is working now. A little bit deeper analysis is much appreciated.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if permission is an issue, why am i able to download file from chrome?

Comment: @AdityaNadig Try if you can download the file from Chrome in a Incognito Window, this should also result in a 401. The token is probably stored in a cookie, so that's why it works from Chrome.

Comment: @robalem there are no tokens with on-premise servers. They use Windows Authentication by default

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that makes sense. I will remove myself from this discussion as you clearly have more experience on the matter :)

Comment: @AdityaNadig we can't know what you're doing, if you're using the same account or if your application runs using a different account, or if you explicitly specify the credentials in chrome instead of having it detect them. The code you posted in both cases has serious bugs and simply doesn't do what you assume it does. Have you tried a *simple* HttpClient call? Just set `UseDefaultCredentials` and make

Comment: @robalem it's not a matter of experience - the two snippets will never work. Although I used to be a SharePoint MVP, 2008-2010. I don't know if there ever was a buggier product, except perhaps Oracle which puts (used to put?) bug reports and patches behind an NDA to maintain the impression of stability

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , my app uses same account, windows authentication. I am not specifying any credentials, explicitly. I will try with ``` UseDefaultCredentials ```  and get back to you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the issue persists. For your benefit i completely serialized exception object and posted it here

Comment: @robalem, i cannot download the file in incognito, it is asking me to login using Microsoft credentials